# How to add condition to EmberJS Input Helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I build a this input `<input class="{{unless isEditing "hidden"}}" />` with the input helper of Ember.js?

Answer (score 3):

You can use parenthesis to have another helper within a helper

```
{{input class=(unless isEditing "hidden")}}
```